# How to access a parent class variable via a child class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I am trying to re-build an OOP approach to mobile verification at the developers discretion. The concept I come up with is to allow for interfaces to manipulate the class. If the class implements the interface, then the verify method will be executed.

The problem I am facing, because I am only used to programming in less strongly-typed languages (PHP) is how to get a protected variable from a class extending the current class.

```
_areaCodes.stream().forEach(o -> {
    try {
        int prefix = Integer.parseInt(this._mobileNumber.charAt(0), this._mobileNumber.charAt(1));
    } catch (Exception e) {}
});
```

This line of code is now giving me an error

> _mobileNumber cannot be resolved or is not a field

Here is my full code and here is [an example](https://3v4l.org/giOLi) I wrote of the same concept in PHP which I am trying to implement in Java.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

interface Verification
{
    public void initVerification();
}

class AreaCode
{
    private int _code;
    private String _country;

    public AreaCode(int code, String country)
    {
        this._code = code;
        this._country = country;
    }

    public int getAreaCode() { return this._code; }
    public String getAreaCountry() { return this._country; }
}

class VerificationHandler
{
    private ArrayList<AreaCode> _areaCodes = new ArrayList<AreaCode>() {{
        this.add(new AreaCode(44, "UNITED KINGDOM"));
        this.add(new AreaCode(91, "INDIA"));
    }};

    public void initVerification()
    {
        if(this instanceof Verification) {
            this.verify();
        }
    }

    protected void verify()
    {
        _areaCodes.stream().forEach(o -> {
        try {
            int prefix = Integer.parseInt(this._mobileNumber.charAt(0), this._mobileNumber.charAt(1));
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    });
    }
}


class Main extends VerificationHandler implements Verification {
    protected String _mobileNumber = "+447435217761";
}

public class Hack1337 { public static void main(String[] args) { new Main(); } }
```

How can I retrieve a variable in a class extending another, ie:

```
class A { public String getB() { return this.b; } }
class B extends A { protected String b = 'A should get this'; }
B b = new B().getB();
```

Comment: Feels like I am reading C code,

Comment: Fields are not polymorphic. If you want `getB()` to return new value in subclass override it in subclass to return that value.

Comment: On another note, `_areaCodes.stream().forEach` can just be `_areaCodes.forEach`. creating a stream just to invoke `forEach` is superfluous.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for that information! How can I do that? I realise Java is more strongly-typed than what I am used to (with coming from PHP background) so I didn't think it was going to be as easy as using `this`, would I have to use `this.getClass.getSubClass()?`

Comment: @Aomine I appreciate that information, I think my original idea was to use `filter()` but ended up going with `forEach()` and just forgot to remove the `stream()` but thanks for pointing it out

Comment: You need a tutorial in inheritance.

Comment: @Raedwald I know the generic inheritance, it should be the other way around and I get that. However, in PHP this is a common way of implementing things as you can see by the PHP example. By appending `implement PaymentVerify` it executes all of the verification methods, and by removing it, it ignores the verification methods. I just wondered if Java could replicate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only instances of class `B`, or sub-classes of `B` can access the `b` instance variable directly (unless you cast `A` to `B` within the body of the `A` class, which is bad practice).

You can give class `A` read-only access to that value by overriding `getB()`:

```
class B extends A
{ 
    protected String b = 'A should get this';

    @Override
    public String getB() { 
        return this.b; 
    } 
}
```

and you may also want to make the `getB()` method abstract in class `A` (which means making class `A` abstract):

```
abstract class A 
{
    public abstract String getB();
}
```

This would only make sense if different sub-classes of `A` are expected to return different things in `getB()`. Otherwise, you may as well move the `b` variable to the base class `A`.

Comment: It is crazy how different it is across different languages, thanks for this answer and I'll try to implement this now! I'll mark as soon as I can.